# Merge cells from different columns in a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that's already bound to a database. For each row in my datagridview, it shows a minimal, avg/nominal and maximum value. However, I'd like it if there is only one value that I give it, to merge cells into one cell, just like in the picture below :

[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVzWg.png)

[image]

Can anyone please help?

I managed so far to merge the cells in the same column with the same values. But I have no idea where to start from now.

Comment: You can handle the RowPrePaint / RowPostPaint events of a DataGridView, so you can define what border are drawn and how the text of *merged*  Cells is drawn. Habdling the `CellPainting` event may be also required, depending on the implementation -- It's not that easy to handle, if you allow editing

Comment: I did that for the vertical grids, and I think I'm going to do something similar for horizontal grids

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to merge cells in DataGridView control. But you can embed Excel control instead of DataGridView.

Comment: Will I need to export my application to excel?

Comment: It's an idea to use Excel instead of your app if you need state-of-the-art formatting, but I proposed just to embed Excel control into your form instead of DataGridView control.

Comment: I'm gonna have to export the file to excel anyways, so I think I'm going with that